# How to create 1 webview app for multiple websites

Tags: android, web-applications, webview

Is it possible to create android app 1 app using webview that has (runs) multiple websites in it instead of just one website

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by using WebView that has multiple websites? You are able to visit any website in any given WebView.

Comment: I mean i want to create an android app with Webview but I don't want to limit that app to one website I want to install multiple websites url in it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible. Obviously, only one webpage can be displayed in the WebView at a time, but using `WebView.loadURL()`, you can change the web site.